# How to serialize a object to CBOR with Newtonsoft.Json.Cbor

Tags: c#, .net, json, cbor

Has anyone used `Newtonsoft.Json.Cbor` to serialize a `.NET` object to a `CBOR` array? How is its performance when serializing a big object to `CBOR` array with `C#` - I expect a `LOH` will be generated.

Could you provide the sample code that you have done?